# How to store intent inside the android local database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I'm having problem in storing the intent.putExtra inside the android local database. I am creating a game like 4Pics1Word for my project. It has only 25 levels so I created 25 activities and I randomized it. After solving a particular activity, it will then be removed to the ArrayList of Classes, `ArrayList<Class>`. Now, I used `intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", activityList);` to store the intent and to pass it to the next activity. My problem is I can't store it on local database. When I exit the game the progress is not saved, it starts again from the first level. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Here's my code in my **Main Activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button btnStart;
Context context;
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // We are creating a list, which will store the activities that haven't been opened yet
    ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
    activityList.add(first.class);
    activityList.add(second.class);
    activityList.add(third.class);
    activityList.add(fourth.class);
    activityList.add(fifth.class);

            Random generator = new Random();
            int number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1;

            Class activity = null;

            switch(number) {
                case 1:
                    activity = first.class;
                    activityList.remove(first.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    activity = second.class;
                    activityList.remove(second.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    activity = third.class;
                    activityList.remove(third.class);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    activity = fourth.class;
                    activityList.remove(fourth.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    activity = fifth.class;
                    activityList.remove(fifth.class);
                    break;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
            intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", activityList);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(activityList); // myObject - instance of MyObject
    prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

}

Here's my code in my **first** activity:

```
public class first extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
EditText etAnswer;
Button btnGo;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    etAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnGo:
            String answer = etAnswer.getText().toString();
            if(answer.equals("Jose Rizal") ||  answer.equals("jose rizal") || answer.equals("Rizal") || answer.equals("rizal") ){
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dlgAlert.setMessage("The famous Rizal monument in Luneta was not the work of a Filipino but a Swiss sculptor named Richard Kissling?" +
                        "\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Source: http://www.joserizal.ph/ta01.html");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Did you know that ...");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Next",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
                                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                                activityList = (ArrayList<Class>) extras.get("ACTIVITY_LIST");

                                if(activityList.size() == 0) {
                                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                    CharSequence last = "Congratulations! You just finished the game! Please wait for the next update!";
                                    int durationFinal = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, last, durationFinal);
                                    toast.show();
                                } else {
                                    // Now, the random number is generated between 1 and however many
                                    // activities we have remaining
                                    Random generator = new Random();
                                    int number = generator.nextInt(activityList.size()) + 1;

                                    Class activity = null;

                                    // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
                                    switch(number) {
                                        case 1:
                                            // We will open the first remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(0);
                                            // We will now remove that activity from the list
                                            activityList.remove(0);
                                            break;
                                        case 2:
                                            // We will open the second remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(1);
                                            activityList.remove(1);
                                            break;
                                        case 3:
                                            // We will open the third remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(2);
                                            activityList.remove(2);
                                            break;
                                        case 4:
                                            // We will open the fourth remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(3);
                                            activityList.remove(3);
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            // We will open the fifth remaining activity of the list
                                            activity = activityList.get(4);
                                            activityList.remove(4);
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    // Note: in the above, we might not have 3 remaining activities, for example,
                                    // but it doesn't matter because that case wouldn't be called anyway,
                                    // as we have already decided that the number would be between 1 and the number of
                                    // activities left.


                                    // Starting the activity, and passing on the remaining number of activities
                                    // to the next one that is opened
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
                                    intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", activityList);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                dlgAlert.create().show();

            }else{
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Wrong! Try Again.";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `I created 25 activities`. Don't do that.

Comment: How can I create a 4Pics1Word game? I only do that because I'm a beginner on android and I don't how any way to do the game. Considering that is has only 25 levels.

Comment: If you are using the same design across all levels then you only need 1 single activity. It is just the information in screen that is changed.

Comment: how can I do that? pleasee helpppp

Comment: Enzokie is right. All you have to do is change the values of what is shown in the view as well as the images, you don't need to create 25 activities once a person got a correct answer. Imagine using switch(level) then so on.

Comment: So basically I just need to randomized the pictures but they must also be related to each other. How can i do that?

Comment: "they must also be related to each other" -- A **relation**al database? SQLite is built into Android

Comment: what I mean is example the answer should be Apple so the activity must display 4 pictures that relates to apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Everytime you come to `MainActivity` , you new an ArrayList and add all the activities rather than get the cache from your local `SharedPreferences` .
2. When you finish one game in an Activity , you did not save your progress in cache.

After updating the arrayList,save your arrayList like this :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(activityList); // myObject - instance of MyObject
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

And when you want to read the arrayList saved ,do like this:

```
String arrayStr = mPrefs.getString("myObject","defValue");
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Class> array = gson.fromGson(arrayStr,new TypeToken<List<Class>>(){}.getType());
if(array==null){
    array = new ArrayList<>();
    array.add(...);
}
```

Comment: That is included in my main activity. I'm having problem in saving the arraylist and then getting it again in the next activity in local storage

Comment: So is there any Exception or something?If so ,show the log plz.

Comment: No. I just can't store the updated ArrayList on the local database.

Comment: After finishing a game instead of saving it cache where can i save it and how?

Comment: Do the same as what you did in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. :\

Comment: Oh I got it now.. but I'm having an error on reading the arraylist saved. Where should I put this?

`String arrayStr = mPrefs.getString("myObject","defValue");
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Class> array = gson.fromGson(arrayStr,new TypeToken<List<Class>>(){}.getType());`

Comment: Everytime when you enter the mainactivity. And remenber to change the ArrayList in SharedPreferences when you finish one goal .

Comment: So I should put it on the "onCreate" method? The application won't run. It always forced closing. 

I put the `SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(activityList); // myObject - instance of MyObject
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();` in between `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Here's my MainActivity source code:
https://paste.ofcode.org/34RzkFLLckudBAdUWcNYtGi

Here's my first.class source code:
https://paste.ofcode.org/PQV2EcLpyutmVuXenDXMLM

Here's my second.class source code:
https://paste.ofcode.org/36HYf7gEvHzxzHNYgCi8j5G

Comment: There's still an error on switch statement.
"Cannot resolve symbol "activityList" on each cases. :(

Here: https://ibb.co/jzKROv

Comment: - - You must be very new ~~ [hope this can help](https://paste.ofcode.org/3aQQfZgSTGZNbEy3hjDKXtc) declare your varible in Class field.

Comment: The application won't open. It forced closed. I was thinking because of this `SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(activityList); // myObject - instance of MyObject
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();`

maybe I should put it in the **first.class** and **second.class** rather than the **MainActivity.class**

I'm not sure though but I'm gonna try